# Why can't I push the function parameter into an array?

Tags: ruby, function, collatz

I'm trying to find the length of this collatz sequence. If I change `test_array << number` to `puts number`, I'm able to output each of the numbers in the sequence but for some reason, I cannot get this function to push the number into the array before returning a new value into the function. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
test_array = []

def collatz_sequence(number)
  return number if number==1
  if number%2==0
    test_array << number
    return collatz_sequence(number/2)
  else
    test_array << number
    return collatz_sequence(3*number+1)

 end
end

puts collatz_sequence(13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local variable cannot take a scope beyond a method definition. Use an instance variable instead.

```
@test_array = []

def collatz_sequence(number)
  return 1 if number == 1
  @test_array << number
  collatz_sequence(number.even? ? number / 2 : 3 * number + 1)
end

collatz_sequence(13) # => 1
@test_array # => [13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2]
```

But I don't see much point in returning 1 at the end. Including that in `@test_array` makes more sense:

```
@test_array = []

def collatz_sequence(number)
  @test_array << number
  collatz_sequence(number.even? ? number / 2 : 3 * number + 1) unless number == 1
end

collatz_sequence(13)
@test_array # => [13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

But this is not a good practice because the array and the procedure of the method have dependency. A better way to do it is:

```
def collatz_sequence(number, test_array = [])
  return if number == 1
  collatz_sequence(number.even? ? number / 2 : 3 * number + 1, test_array)
end

collatz_sequence(13)
```

Comment: Thank you all! I accepted this answer because it was the longest but everyone was so helpful. Much appreciation!

Answer (score 2):

`test_array = []` is out of scope. `def` creates a new scope so you cannot access the value of  `test_array` from within the method.

One way around this is to make `test_array` an instance variable: `@test_array`

Answer (score 1):

what about this implementation:

```
    def collatz_sequence(number)
      array = [number]
      if number%2==0
        array += collatz_sequence(number/2)
      elsif number != 1
        array += collatz_sequence(3*number+1)
      end
      return array
    end

    puts collatz_sequence(13)
```